# Force Facebook videos embedded in a website default to HD?

Tags: facebook, embed

There is a way to force YouTube videos embedded in a website to play back at HD quality, simply by adding some lines to the embed code (`?feature=player_detailpage&VQ=HD720`). For additional details [see here](http://thenewcode.com/717/Force-Embedded-YouTube-Videos-To-Play-In-HD).

However, I have searched extensively for a way to do this with Facebook videos embedded in a website and have had no luck. Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this? Is there a line of code or a parameter I can add to Facebook's embed code to force an embedded video to play back in HD quality?

Am I missing something in the advanced documentation for [Facebook's embedded video player](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player) or their video player API?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I may have determined the answer. After reviewing some old guidelines that Facebook used to have, as well as their [current recommendations](https://www.facebook.com/help/124738474272230?helpref=related) for high quality videos, I began rendering my videos with the following settings:

```
H.264 Codec
Progressive

VBR, 2 pass
Target bit rate = 5
Max bit rate =10

Frame size = 1920 x 1080
Frame rate = 29.97fps

AAC, 192 kbps
44.1 Hz, Stereo
```

Once I render my videos with the settings above, Facebook appears to create several versions (240p, 360p, 480p, 720p, and 1080p) and then serves up the best file depending on the viewer's internet connection. This is true when the video is played on Facebook.com and when the video is embedded on a website.

The videos I've been uploading only get a handful of views, but at least they're at the best quality. Can anyone else confirm if these render settings are working for them as well?